# Getting Fixnum error on check_box helper on collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<% Topic.all.each do |topic| %>
  <%= f.check_box "topic_ids[]", topic.id, false %>
<% end %>
```

That is inside a `form_for`.

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum
```

Around the main `check_box` line.

My `Topic` model actually looks like this, and I would like for the checkboxes to display the name of the topics on each checkbox:

```
# Table name: topics
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `check_box_tag` instead of `f.check_box`.

```
check_box_tag "topic_ids[]",topic.id
```

The difference is `f.check_box` is for model-bounded forms and the value supplied to the check box is implicit from the given model and doesn't need to be provided.

Comment: Perfect, this worked. The only other issue I am having now is with the `f.label`. It automatically changes the case from `AAPL` to `Aapl`. Why does it do that?

Comment: Or I guess another question is, how do I display the name beside the checkbox without using the `f.label` helper? Or is the only way to do it by using a label?

Comment: try this for your automatically changes the case from - <%= f.label :xyz, "xyz name", :class => "your class name" %>

Comment: for your second question - without using f.label helper you can simply  add text in a div or span

Comment: if your text automatically change than you can add into your css - text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: The issue is that I want the name to be dynamically generated. Not statically in the double quotes. I would rather not have to use CSS to transform the case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17547/discussion-between-dipak-panchal-and-marcamillion)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<% Topic.all.each do |topic| %>
  <%= f.check_box "topic_ids[]", topic.id.to_s, false %>
<% end %>
```